# Pass multiple selected options to firebase query in angular (angularfire2)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to display the multiple users data as they select from the dropdown menu in the table. On single user selected it is working but when multiple are selected nothing comes. Can we do this in angularfire? 
Any help will be much appreciated. 
Html code -

[image: Here's how the dropdown looks like]

```
<mat-form-field class="matselect">
              <mat-label>Select User</mat-label>
              <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedUsername" multiple  (selectionChange)="selectedName()">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let userName of filteredUsername"  [value]="userName">{{userName}} </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

<table>
<tr *ngFor="let post of posts | async" > 
          <td>{{post.userName}}</td>
          <td>{{ post.number }}</td>
          <td>{{ post.callLength}}</td>
</tr> </table>
```

Component.ts file -

```
selectedName() {
    console.log(this.selectedUsername);
    this.posts = this.afs.collection<Post>('data', ref => ref.where('userName', '==', this.selectedUsername)).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: You can use forkJoin to run requests in parallel for each choice.

Comment: And how it works. I mean any sample. I don't know anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

What you would like to do is make multiple `OR` operations, which is one of the limitations of firebase (angularfire is just a wrapper for firebase), as mentioned in the **[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)**:

> Query limitations:
>
> Logical `OR` queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each `OR` condition and merge the query results in your app.

So I suggest you run all requests for each username in parallel using `forkJoin`.

Sample:

```ts
userNames = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];

const reqs = this.userNames.map(x => this.afs.collection<Post>('data', ref => ref.where('userName', '==', x)).valueChanges());
this.posts = forkJoin(...reqs).pipe(
  map(val => {
    return val.map((data, i, arr) => {
      return { userName: this.userNames[i], posts: data };
    });
  })
);
```

Now you end up with an observable array, which looks like:

```ts
[
  {
    userName: 'name1',
    posts: [/** data from db here **/]
  },
  // ....
]
```

You can modify the structure you want inside `map` to the choosing you want the data to be structured.